# How do I make a POST request to server on company network

Tags: vb.net, post

I've been given some data to perform a call to ping a server that is contained within our work network. This call must happen from within the vb.net application I've built, but I'm really struggling to even get started on this one. I've tried creating a WebRequest, but I'm not even sure that's correct.

Here's what I have ("xxx" replacing sensitive parts):

```
POST /xxx/XmlService HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx001 (this is just the server name)
Content-Type: text/xml
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: xxx (long token)

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xxx version="1.0">
        <Request
                Object="System"
                Action="Ping">
        </Request>
</xxx>
```

And I'm expecting an XML response back.

Can someone at least point me in the right direction? Thank you immensely!

Comment: Where I'm struggling, assuming a Webrequest is correct, is that I don't have a url, only a server address. So I've tried using \\(server name)\, which might be ok? but then what about that parameter after the "POST" in the data I was given? What am I supposed to do with that? Also can't figure out the Postman-Token.

Comment: please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909173/vb-net-sending-http-post-request-using-sockets

Comment: Hmm, looks like some similar syntax, but a socket connection seems to require an IP address, correct?

Comment: You can simply mention the server like this: `client.Connect("myserver.com", 123);`

Comment: Is "client" a variable in that case?

Comment: In the link I gave with the already written answer juste put the hostname as `"myserver.com"`

Comment: Are you meaning to use that poster's upper segment where he's using the socket method, but make the hostname variable = my server name & ".com"? That doesn't do anything. You saw that I don't have a url, just a server name, right?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to connect. Here's how for those who follow (using same replace "xxx" strings as in OP):

```
    Dim uriTest As Uri
    uriTest = New Uri("http://xxx001/xxx/XmlService")


    Dim requestStr As String
    requestStr = Strings.Trim("POST /xxx/XmlService HTTP/1.1" & Environment.NewLine &
                              "Host: xxx001" & Environment.NewLine &
                              "Content-Type: text/xml" & Environment.NewLine &
                              "Cache-Control: no-cache" & Environment.NewLine &
                              "Postman-Token: 6672bfe9-6d44-4770-869d-4f08c24ab143" & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine &
                              "<?xml version=""1.0"" ?>" & Environment.NewLine &
                              "<xxx version=""1.0"">" & Environment.NewLine &
                              "<Request" & Environment.NewLine &
                              "Object=""System""" & Environment.NewLine &
                              "Action=""Ping"">" & Environment.NewLine &
                              "</Request>" & Environment.NewLine &
                              "</xxx>")
    Dim req As HttpWebRequest, webreq As WebRequest
    webreq = WebRequest.Create(uriTest)
    req = CType(webreq, HttpWebRequest)

    req.Method = "POST"

    Dim dataStream As Stream = req.GetRequestStream()
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestStr)
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()
    Dim response As WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
    Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()
```